# When to pick JSONObject vs JSONArray

Tags: json

I am working on a requirement to save the data in the form. But I am not really sure to save in the form JSONArray or JSONObject. I need to save City and State details of a user.

I am really confused to choose a format. To be frank I don't have any idea of cons and pros of JSONArray vs JSONObject. I have tried to find it online but most of it just says about the differences but not which one to pick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving data that has a cardinality greater than one (eg user phone numbers / emails), use an array. Else, if the data are just attributes of an object, use JSONObject. A user generally has a single residence in generic user modeling.

Comment: Thanks for the response.